# How can I get null values row using Criteria Builder in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g, hibernate-criteria

I am using criteria builder query to get rows of two dependent table from oracle database. I am using two tables T1 and T2 and i am taking ID column from T1 in T2 Table as T1_id Name column and it may be null in T2_Table when I have select fields from T2_Table and if T1_id column are null then i am not getting rows which contains null value of T1_Id column so how can I get all rows from T2 table if field of Table T1 in Table T2 are null.

I have two tables like:-

Table T1 which has field ID,T1_Name, Description.

Table T2  which has field ID,T2_Name,T1_id.

T1_id column in table T2 are ID column of Table T1.

I am using criteria Builder Query to get results of T2 Table but if T1_id column is null then i m not getting rows.

**Code are:-**

```
 CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Task> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Table_T2.class);
        Root<Task> taskRoot = criteria.from(Table_T2.class);
        criteria.orderBy(getCriteriaBuilder().desc(taskRoot.get(Table_T2.ID)));
        criteria.multiselect(taskRoot.get(Table_T2.T1_id),taskRoot.get(Table_T2.ID),taskRoot.get(Table_T2.T2_Name))
```

In above mention code if my T1_ID is null then not giving rows.

**Data in my Table T2 are:-**

```
ID  T2_Name  T1_id
1    test    t1_1
22   test1   null
```

I am getting only first row not getting second row.